# group by function with special

Tags: oracle

I have a table

```
dated          abc     def     gh     jkl    
01.05.2016     2       12      23     16  
02.05.2016     11      7       5      8  
03.05.2016     6       4       9      1
```

.......

From this table I want to create a table as

```
dated          abc     def     gh     jkl    
01.05.2016     2       12      23     16  
02.05.2016     13      19      28     24  
03.05.2016     19      23      37     25
```

......
So, actually I want all the values to add but only for dates less than the selected date...
How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like running total, you could use `windowed` `SUM`:

```
SELECT dated
       ,SUM(abc) OVER(ORDER BY dated) AS abc
       ,SUM(def) OVER(ORDER BY dated) AS def
       ,SUM(gh)  OVER(ORDER BY dated) AS gh
       ,SUM(jkl) OVER(ORDER BY dated) AS jkl
FROM t
ORDER BY dated;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CDRTO24113)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═════╦═════╦════╦═════╗
║        dated        ║ abc ║ def ║ gh ║ jkl ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════╬═════╬════╬═════╣
║ 05.01.2016 00:00:00 ║   2 ║  12 ║ 23 ║  16 ║
║ 05.02.2016 00:00:00 ║  13 ║  19 ║ 28 ║  24 ║
║ 05.03.2016 00:00:00 ║  19 ║  23 ║ 37 ║  25 ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════╩═════╩════╩═════╝
```

**EDIT:**

> *, how to get the count as well, like for the first row, count is 1, and for second row it is 2 as another column and so on....*

You could use `COUNT` or `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ...
  ,COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY dated) AS cnt
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/HXH78737)**</kbd>

> *can I use some calculations as well... like sum(abc) over (order by dated)/count(*)*100/3 as NMU*

Yes you can do a whole range of calculation. But be aware that some operation has to be wrapped with derived table (CTE/subquery):

```
sum(abc) over (order by dated)/COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY dated)*100.0/3 as NMU
```

**EDIT:**

> *It is working fine except one thing, that the sum shall be only for the month wise or quarter wise, means the addition shall goes on only till the month end, so when month/quarter changes the value shall start from the beginning again*

Then you need to partition by (year, month) or (year, quarter):

```
SELECT dated
       ,SUM(abc) OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(year from dated),
                                   EXTRACT(month from dated) ORDER BY dated) AS abc
```

or:

```
SELECT dated,
      ,SUM(abc) OVER(PARTITION BY to_char(dated, 'YYYY Q') ORDER BY dated) AS abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...along with it, how to get the count as well, like for the first row, count is 1, and for second row it is 2 as another column and so on....

Comment: with this function of `over(order by)`, can I use some calculations as well... like `sum(abc) over (order by dated)/count(*)*100/3 as NMU`..

Comment: It is working fine except one thing, that the sum shall be only for the month wise or quarter wise, means the addition shall goes on only till the month end, so when month/quarter changes the value shall start from the beginning again (i.e. the first day value)......